# How to crop a circle shaped image and then set it inside another image?

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, canvas, crop

I'm working on an pet finding app and I need to crop the pet's avatar into a small circle that will later be "merged"/combined with an outline and then passed as a Marker to static google maps. I want to make this on the front-end, because doing this on the back-end would require (if the service expands or grows too much) some more space management for images.

This is the outline:[image: Profile Outline]

The result should look like this:
[image]

The profile picture might be of any size bigger than the outline, so they will be of any shape (generally square or rectangular).

I'm trying to figure out if I can do this entirely on the front-end. As far as I know, I can:

- Take the profile image and insert it into a canvas
- Then crop it in a circular shape (don't know how to do this)
- Transform it back into an image (not sure if this is needed)
- Add it to another canvas so I can combine it with the outline
- Save it as an image and then send it to static google maps as a marker

I thought if I made the canvas borders round (with css border-radius) it could work, but it didn't.

So, for the question itself, can an image be cropped into a circle with just JavaScript and Canvas (on the front-end) or should I make this on the back-end? And if it can, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you style the marker at all with css?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126536/how-to-get-a-rotated-crop-of-an-image-with-html5-canvas

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/27DvU/ You can edit it with CSS then use javascript to give it a background url

Comment: @BeatAlex I can't style it with css because **static** google maps only accepts images as custom markers

Comment: Look at this then: [Link 1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/1/)

Comment: @BeatAlex Does that work on static google maps too? Because I need those as there's no need for the entire javascript map which is way larger than static maps.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I could get the static map then place the css marker on the middle of it, I'll try to see what comes up and come back later, thanks guys :)

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work on a static map.

Comment: I did it with CSS at the end, thanks. You should at it (if you still care about this though) as an answer, :) Ps: I'm still intrigued as if it can be achieved through canvas though